# Edit data using arcobjects by SOE Web Services on Arcgis Server 10.0

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-server, server-object-extension

I trying to develop WebService which main purpose is enable editing data. My Web Service get as param information about records, tables etc. Code looks like below:

```
IFeatureWorkspace ifw = null;
        IWorkspaceEdit iwep = null;
        try {
            ifw = new IFeatureWorkspaceProxy(new IVersionProxy(currentUserVersion));
            iwep = new IWorkspaceEditProxy(ifw);
            iwep.startEditing(false);
            iwep.startEditOperation();
            performOperation(mergeData, ifw, iwep);
//this method make store on records
        } catch (AutomationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                iwep.stopEditOperation();
                iwep.stopEditing(true);
 } catch (AutomationException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }
```

Everything works fine for one single request, but above code is horrible slow for multirequest for different version. Because different people has own version which is used to editing. I think the most time take startEditOperation and startEditing. Everything starts as capability of MXD file. Anyone can give me a solution how to using soe web services give capablities for editing data which will have a quite good performance?

Comment: Esri suggests using [Feature Services](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/What_is_a_feature_service/009300000020000000/) to provide editing.  Why not use that?

Comment: You have right. But Feature Service currently cannot work with versions.

Comment: Ok. Maybe someone can explain me, when edit session should be started in SOE Web Services?

Comment: Are you sure startedit/stopedit is taking most of the time? My experience is that every store you make on a table takes long time. If your users updates many features at the same time you should use an insert cursor.

Comment: How do your users call the SOE? Are there many users? If you have only a few users you could maybe dedicate a context for each user already connected to the right version. That may require using non-pooled contexts that the webservice hogs for a long time.

Comment: Stefan, thanks for your answers. I will check a Insert Cursors. And answering for your question, I will have about 200 users.